# Avoid writing too many getters and setters in Go

Tags: go, interface, garbage-collection, getter-setter

I am implementing a message passing system in Go. So I have a general interface called `Msg`. The `Msg` interface defines many common fields such as source, destination, send time, receive time, etc. I cannot define a full list of `Msg`s since I want the library users to define the concrete type of `Msg`s.

To provide a concrete type of `Msg`, a user would need to implement a large list of getters and setters, which is very annoying.

One solution I tried is to provide a simple base class like `MsgBase` and defines all the common properties and getters and setters. And for each concrete type of `Msg`, I embed a pointer to the `MsgBase`. This solution works.

But then, I want to embed a value version of the `MsgBase` in the concrete `Msg` types. This is because such `Msg`s are created too many times in the execution and dynamically allocating a `MsgBase` would increase the garbage collection overhead. I really want all the `Msg`s are allocated statically since they are passed by the components and should never be shared. If I use the value version of the `MsgBase`, I cannot use the setters defined in the `MsgBase`.

I wonder if there is any simple solution to this problem?

EDIT: Adding sample code

```golang
type Msg interface {
    // Agent is another interface
    Src() Agent
    SetSrc(a Agent)
    Dst() Agent
    SetDst(a Agent)

    ... // A large number of properties
}

type MsgBase struct {
    src, dst Agent
    ... // Properties as private fields.
}

func (m MsgBase) Src() Agent {
    return m.src
}

func (m *MsgBase) SetSrc(a Agent) {
    m.src = a
}

... // Many other setters and getters for MsgBase


type SampleMsg struct {
    MsgBase // option1
    *MsgBase // option2
}
```

Comment: Are you embedding `MsgBase` in the concrete message types? Can you post a sample of the code?

Comment: @AndySchweig Yes, I require my library user to embed `MsgBase` in their concrete types. I am adding a very simple sample code in the original post.

Comment: Remember that interfaces should describe *behavior*, not *data*. If you find yourself trying to establish a contract on fields rather than methods, you might need to reconsider your design, because you don't have real interfaces at that point. Attempting to recreate Java/C#-style OOP in Go will not yield good results.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for the comment. It really helps. It seems I need to reconsider the system design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Go doesn't have object-oriented inheritance in the same way Java does.  This sounds like you're trying to write an abstract base class that encapsulates all of the parts of a "message"; that's not really typical Go style.

The fields you're describing are typical message metadata.  You can encapsulate this metadata in a pure-data structure.  It doesn't necessarily need any behavior, and it doesn't necessarily need getter and setter methods.

```
type MessageMeta struct {
  Source Agent
  Destination Agent
}
```

The more object-oriented approach is to say a message has a (mutable) metadata block and a (immutable, encoded) payload.

```
import "encoding"

type Message interface {
  encoding.BinaryMarshaler // requires MarshalBinary()
  Meta() *MessageMeta
}

type SomeMessage struct {
  MessageMeta
  Greeting string
}

func (m *SomeMessage) Meta() *MessageMeta {
  return &m.MessageMeta
}

func (m *SomeMessage) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
  return []byte(m.Greeting), nil
}
```

A more procedural approach that passes these two things separately is also reasonable.  In this case there's no interface for what's a "message", you just pass on the encoded payload; standard-library interfaces like [`encoding.BinaryMarshaler`](https://godoc.org/encoding#BinaryMarshaler) could make sense here.  You might include this in a lower-level interface that's part of your library.

```
func Deliver(meta *MessageMeta, payload []byte) error { ... }
```

Translating one to the other is easy

```
func DeliverMessage(m Message) error {
  payload, err := m.Payload()
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  meta := m.Meta()
  return Deliver(meta, payload)
}
```

If one of the metadata fields is "delivered at", making sure to pass a pointer to the metadata object all the way through the chain lets you update that field in the original object.

I would not worry about garbage collection as a first-class consideration, except to avoid being overtly wasteful, and to check up on object allocation if GC starts showing up in profiles.  Creating two objects instead of one probably isn't going to be a huge problem here.